# iOS no communication between iPhone app and MySQL database via PHP

Tags: php, mysql, ios, nsdata, nsurl

I need help trying to figure out why my iPhone app is not communicating with my PHP. I have a text field where the user can enter a message and there is a button that is supposed to tell the app when the text has been entered and needs to be posted to my mySQL database.

My PHP and iOS code are pasted below, but I also included some debugging statements here.

I put a break at the line `if([serverOutput...)` and at that point I get the following:

```
alertsuccess    UIAlertView *   0x00000000
dataURL NSData *    0x00000000 
messageString   __NSCFString *  0x0685e7a0 @"hi"
serverOutput    __NSCFConstantString *  0x00b75a7c
url NSURL * 0x06869540 @"http://www.mysite.com/connect.php?message=hi"
```

From the debug breakpoint, I would expect serverOutput to say "OK" but it's blank, which I believe means that it did not connect with my PHP.  Your help is appreciated on how to fix this.

```
<?php
// Connecting, selecting database
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password")
or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("mydb") or die('Could not select database');

// Performing SQL query
$query = "INSERT INTO messages (message,date) VALUES ('$_GET["message"]',NOW())";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());

echo "OK";

// Free resultset
mysql_free_result($result);

// Closing connection
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

iPhone code

```
- (IBAction)postmessage:(id)sender {

self.message = self.messageField.text;
NSString *messageString = self.message;
UIAlertView *alertsuccess;

 //construct an URL for your script, containing the encoded text for parameter value
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:
 [NSString stringWithFormat:
 @"http://www.mysite.com/connect.php?message=%@",messageString]];

NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

if([serverOutput isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {

   alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Posted" message:@"Done"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

} else {
    alertsuccess = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Done"
                                                          delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];

}
[alertsuccess show];

}
```

Comment: Did you check your web server's logs to see if there really WAS a hit on the php script? It may very well be connecting but your script has an error which kills it before any output occurs.

Comment: I wouldn't access remote resources like this. Try and load it in safari on the device to see if it works first though.

Comment: Thanks Marc and Jesse for your feedback
@Marc: I am not quite sure how to check my server logs, but I will look into this.  Besides this, did I implement NSURL and NSData correctly?

Comment: @Jesse How do you recommend to access mySQL database?  I actually don't own an iphone right now and relying on the simulator.  Does it make a difference using the simulator versus running on the iphone?

Comment: You need to look into NSURLConnection

Answer (score 1):

Error is here `$query = "INSERT INTO messages (message,date) VALUES ('$_GET["message"]',NOW())";`

Should be

```
$query = "INSERT INTO messages (message,date) VALUES ('" . $_GET["message"] . "', NOW())";
```

or

```
$query = "INSERT INTO messages (message,date) VALUES ('${_GET["message"]}', NOW())";
```

Comment: I would be very cautious using that as it's vulnerable to injection.

Comment: That's true, I just pointed OP to the place in the code which has a syntax error