# Directly perform SQL queries from iPhone to an online server

Tags: sql, ios, database

I'm a newbie and tend to do a simple iOS applications.

The mission is making an app that does the registeration for a person and then upload that data to an online server.

In detail, I want to `insert`, `delete`, `update` data directly to online server.

Would anyone show me what I have to do with (tool, library...)?

I have worked with SQlite to make a local database for the iPhone and it worked well, now it is about dealing with an online server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For performing remote request there are two ways:

1) https://github.com/smhuang426/MySqueakQl - this is "basic" implementation for remote access to DB. http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/ - more advanced, in articles you may some instructions how use this framework.  In this case you use SQL C API and you can write your own special classes. Example: http://blog.iosplace.com/?p=30  , http://zetcode.com/tutorials/mysqlcapitutorial/ and description of C API http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-function-overview.html

2)  PHP script that posted on online server, you use async ASIHTTP (or ordinary NSRequest) that send to this script, and script works directly with sql DB on tis server. Example ( [iOS no communication between iPhone app and MySQL database via PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11715521/ios-no-communication-between-iphone-app-and-mysql-database-via-php)). In this case you achieved more security, but also there some limitations like decrease of app's speed and server must supply PHP.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

What you need is some kind of remote API available which you will use to interface the iPhone application and say, a MySQL database.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail,because i am definitely a newbie in this field.