# Connect to MySQL/Oracle db from objective-c without additional layer

Tags: mysql, objective-c, ios, database, oracle

I would like to connect from an objective-c iOS app to a MySQL or Oracle database (both options are possible).

For the sake of simplicity I would like to **avoid any additional layer at server side** (like PHP/ruby/python...) and instead, directly query the database from my app.

Are they any framework or tutorial I should know about?

Comment: Look this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11813890/directly-perform-sql-queries-from-iphone-to-an-online-server/11952006#11952006, I hope this help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This site might be useful for you:

http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/

Even though it seems to be possible, I advice you to consider other ways because, like the website says, there is no guarantee that apple will accept your app.

Hope i helped you